# InnoDB: The OS said file flush did not succeed

Tags: mysql

[ERROR] InnoDB: The OS said file flush did not succeed
とはどういうエラーなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

変更をにディスクに書き込むようOSに指示したものの、「書き込みに失敗した」と返事が返ってきた、といった意味合いです。保存に失敗した、とでも言いましょうか。

原因としては、ファイルシステムの空き容量が不足している、ファイルシステムやディスクに何らかの障害が発生している、などが考えられます。

MySQL側でもそのエラーに続けてもう少し情報があるかもしれませんが、なければOSのエラーログ（Linuxなら `dmesg` とか `/var/log/messages` とか）をご確認ください。

[MySQL :: Error: the OS said file flush did not succeed, Help!](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,66995,66995#msg-66995)